Using dlib+ opencv on windows and using raspberry pi after modeling
I am currently preparing to become a newly minted senior developer.
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat') in a package called dlib
If the dat format is called a model, it has the function of finding feature points of a person's face when giving an image to deep learning.
Can I just provide the photo or can I leave it without data labeling?
If you want to create input data using eyebrow color, eye color, skin color, and both cheeks,
I am curious if it is possible to separate the photo data and labeling data into test train valid.
I actually don't know how to install dlib. Thank you, seniors, for your help!!
First, I tried to use other data created in Git, but
The dlib module could not be installed, and if the user takes a picture by turning on the camera function using opencv,
The model needs to learn from those photos, but I'm not sure how to do that part.
Is it right to do deep learning? I'm not sure if I can just use machine learning.
